# jparepository cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to use JpaRepository but I am getting this error "jparepository cannot be resolved to a type."

My maven dependency is

`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.2.RELEASE
 

com.example
accessing-data-jpa
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
accessing-data-jpa
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

My student class is

```
package Repositry;

public interface Student_Repo extends JpaRepositry  {

}
```

Please let me know what I have done wrong

Answer (score 2):

Typo here.

It is `JpaRepository` not `JpaRepositry`

Also it expects 2 parameters.

1. Entity class
2. Type of primary key field (Integer/Long)

Like below.

```
Student_Repo extends JpaRepository<Student,Long>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur

1. As spelling error
2. If you commented out the Jpa dependency in pom.xml or didn't add it in the first place.

   `<dependency>  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> </dependency>`

HTH